# Find logon count user on workstation

Tags: powershell, powershell-4.0

I have a script that finds the computer users are logged onto.  Issue is it may return a few results as the user may have logged onto a few different machines e.g. a server a co worker and therefore there maybe 3 different hostnames listed.

I'm looking to use PowerShell to find out which computer is their primary workstation.

I was thinking I could count the no. of logons per machine as they would have logged on to their primary workstation most often, whichever has the most logons then would be their primary workstaion.

I searched and tested methods using `Get-EventLog` etc. but nothing so far works.

Perhaps there is another clever way of determining which of e.g. 3 workstations is the most used by the user? probing the file system?

Comment: If you use apps hosted on terminal servers, you may find users log into those servers (e.g. a few times a day) more often than they do their own machine (~once a day).  Another way to check if they're the primary user is to see if anyone else logs into that machine; most users machines will mostly only be logged into by them.

Comment: Although this isn't a "make this script for me" place, I would be curious how to do this as well

Comment: Got admin on all these boxes? Check the timestamp for when their profile folder (eg. C:\Users\confuseis) was created. Pretty good chance they logged into their own machine before any others. Not foolproof if they had to flatten and reimage their computer, but more often than not it'd be their main machine.

Comment: You may find people around here both more willing and more able to provide help if you actually *showed* what you tried so far, *showed* the results, and explained how *exactly* they were different from what you expected.

Comment: Regarding querying the timestamp of the user profile Yes I have an admin account. and I have looked into this and  locally I can use  get-item c:\users\user1 | select "creationtime"    problem is this get-item  cmdlet cannot be used with the -computername parameter so I cant run it against remote machines.   I looked up more and see invoke-command as an option but it means trifling with the clients machines enable winrm etc.  so thats out.   Im looking at using get-wmiobject but cant find any example of getting the creationtime against a remote machine that works.

Comment: C:\Users\bicard>wmic path Win32_directory WHERE name='c:\\users\bicard\' get creationdate
Node -computer1
ERROR:
Description = Invalid query